# mongo check if point is inside stored polygons

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have a user collection where each user has a point

userSchema

```
username: string,
location: {
      type: { type: String, default: 'Point' },
  coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [0,0] }
},
```

Also I have a location collection where each location is a polygon.

locationsSchema

```
name: {type: String, required: true},
area: {
  type: { type: String, default: 'Polygon' },
  coordinates: {type: [], required: true }
}
```

Now I say I have selected 2 location poygons [id1, id2]. I want to find all the users inside this location i.e. inside poygon id1 and id2.
How do i go about this?

I know if i have one point given I can find polygons like this

```
db.locations.find({"loc":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[x, y]}}}}
```

But what If i was given Polygons and want to find all users inside it?

**EDIT**

I figured out for one polygon I can do this

```
User.find({location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: locations[0] }}});
```

How can i go about multiple polygons?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this Problem. I solved it simply by creating Multipolygon iterating through all polygons.

```
var loc_json = {type: 'MultiPolygon', coordinates: []};
var flat_loc = _.flatMap(all_loc, 'locations');
var locations = [];
_.forEach(flat_loc, function(loc) {
   locations.push(loc.area.coordinates);
});
loc_json.coordinates = locations;
User.find({location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: loc_json }}});
```